# MVC (MVC3) checking is a Model exists or has values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a working DropDownListFor which gets the data from a selectlist which is Model.IssueSocialSec  and then setting the value coming from the database is  Model.SocialDBValue

However, when I click a Edit link which with query a repository passing the Model back to the page, that works, but if I do a needed redirect route to the page and nothing is there to bind the Model, then the page fails.  I'm going to try having it pass back an empty Model, but I figured I would post this as I always like to hear feedback on "best practices" and lessons learned.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSocial, new SelectList(Model.IssueSocialSec, "Value", "Text", Model.SocialDBValue), "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it like this:

```
    ChildInfoModel childviewmodel = new ChildInfoModel();
    return View(childviewmodel);
```

before I was trying to just do:
        `return View()`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to wrap the `DropDownListFor` in a `<form>` with a url pointing to an action that will allow you to edit. The form can use a `GET` request if it's an idempotent operation and you could use JavaScript to submit the form when the value of the `<select>` is changed, falling back to rendering a button for submission for when JavaScript is disabled.

Generally, I structure MVC controllers and actions as so

```
public class ProfilesController : Controller
{
    public IProfileRepository Profiles { get; private set; }

    public ProfilesController(IProfilesRepository profiles)
    {
        Profiles = profiles;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var profiles = Profiles.All();

        return View(new ProfilesModel { Profiles = profiles });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var profile = Profiles.GetById(id);

        return View(new ProfileModel { Profile = profile });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProfileModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var profile = Profiles.GetById(id);       

        // update the profile 
        Mapper.Map(model, profile);

        if (Profiles.Update(profile))
        {
            TempData["message"] = "Profile updated successfully";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
}
```

`Index` will render all the profiles. Against each profile, an `<a>` will be rendered with a URL pointing to Edit and the URL will include the `id` for the profile to edit. `Edit` view will post a form to `Edit` and the profile will be updated with changes from the model.

I recommend looking at something like **[NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)** or **[MVC Music store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)** to get an idea of how they structure their code.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that, ... I am consistently finding that ALL the MVC solutions have "pieces" that are nice, but none end up giving me what I really want. It is nothing like a blueprint for say a house I want to build.  I'm finding it to be like a blueprint for a barn or a shed.  I realize they are not building MY application, but I am not the only developer feeling that NerDinner, MVC Music Store, Sports Store, Silk, ProDinner, and others are not terribly helpful.

Comment: For example:  This is NOT used by anyone ... @Html.EditorForModel()  all that does it plop down all the Model info straight up and down.  Unless I'm missing something, that is for a quick mom and pop shop no frills page.  Hmm, and in my experience, EVEN MOM & POP want fields moved around etc...  Reminds me of the new vs studio lightswitch review I read, ..."makes easy things super easy, and hard things nearly impossible"  ... sorry for the rant.

Comment: They are samples and should be taken as such. The best way I've found to understand the framework is to read through the source code, set breakpoints and debug through the framework code and try to learn something new about it every day.

Comment: You can specify your own templates to use such that `@Html.EditorForModel()` uses your templates for markup.